# Coordinating node - just enough information to perform aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am going through the documentation to better understand the role of coordinating node, the different phases of search request -

I come across a phase -

> Each shard returns just enough information to the coordinating node

What sort of information this phrase refers - "just enough information" ?
If we had complex queries like bool queries, aggregation - I presume coordinating need to execute the same query again to aggregation the results globally, in that case, coordinate node will also have some come kind of lucene engine running to aggregate the results ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coordinating node can have(when act as a data-node and your index shard is present on it) or can't have the data(when used as a dedicated coordinating node or your index's shard isn't present) of your index.

All it does gather the result from all other participating data nodes in the query and create a priority queue and return the top result.

To answer your question,

> I presume coordinating need to execute the same query again to
>   aggregation the results globally, in that case, coordinate node will
>   also have some come kind of lucene engine running to aggregate the
>   results ?

No, the co-ordinating node will not aggregate the results and will not query again to aggregate to produce global results.

You can think of it, you need to get the top 10 documents in your index, assume you have 5 shards and 5 data nodes, then every shard will calcualte the top 10 documents and send it co-ordinating node with the score, now coordinating node, will create a priority queue and returns the top 10 documents, but for that it doesn't have to run another query or it just have to sort the top 50 documents returned from  5 data nodes which already have score and returns the top 10 docs.

Good read on this https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-does-elasticsearch-process-a-query/191181 and https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order

Comment: @you mean, as the score was already present, it doesn't need to do a "real" aggregation but can sort the results ?

Comment: @Nag, exactly :)

Comment: what if in the case of queries where score does not present like filters ? it will probably send any 10 results ?

Comment: @Nag, https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order this will give more details on how filters get executed, tl;dr ES internally does something to send the best 10 results not just random

Comment: awesome , and the other question - once the 10 results returned ( for the example you cited above),  I assume those 40 results will be discarded ? Or is there any config flag to hint coordinating node to hint not to discard but to serve the next client request when the client requests for 10 to 20  (pagination)

Comment: I just did :-), BTW, i sent one "last" ( hopefully) question - please review it. I went through shard cache, didnt get lot of details there -

Comment: Is it possible to give the hint to avoid" fetch" phase - it might not be needed in all the cases ?

Comment: @Nag, what exactly is your use-case, why you want to avoid the fetch phase, can you explain in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212668/discussion-between-nag-and-opster-elasticsearch-ninja).